# Interacting with deepstream.io records server side

Tags: node.js, rethinkdb, deepstream.io

I've been doing some reading up on `deepstream.io` and so far I've discovered the following:

1. <strike>All records are stored in the same table (`deepstream_records` by default)</strike>
2. To interact with this data, the client *can* be used, both client side (browser) and server side (node), but *should* **not** be used on the server side (node).

**Questions:**

- How should I interact with records from the server side?
- Is there something stopping me from changing records in the database?

  - Would changes to records in the database update client subscriptions?
  - Would this be considered bad practice?
- <strike>Why are all the records stored in the same table?</strike>

Data example from RethinkDB:

```
{
  "_d": { },
  "_v": 0,
  "ds_id":  "users/"
}, {
  "_d": { },
  "_v": 0,
  "ds_id":  "users/admin"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Why are all the records stored in the same table?

```
server.set( 'storage', new RethinkDBStorageConnector( { 
  port: 5672, 
  host: 'localhost' ,
    /* (Optional) A character that's used as part of the
    * record names to split it into a tabel and an id part, e.g.
    * 
    * books/dream-of-the-red-chamber
    *
    * would create a table called 'books' and store the record under the name
    * 'dream-of-the-red-chamber'
    */
  splitChar: '/'
}));

server.start();
```

Did you not mention the splitChar? ( It doesn't default )

### How should I interact with records on the server side?

To interact with this data you would create a node client that connects to your server using tcp ( default port 6021 ). The server itself is a very efficient message broker that can distribute messages with low latency, and our recommendation is to not include any custom code that isn't necassary, even when using permissioning and dataTransforms.
https://deepstream.io/tutorials/core/transforming-data

You can see this explained in the FX provider example in the tutorials:

https://deepstream.io/tutorials/core/active-data-providers

And the tank game tutorial example:

https://github.com/deepstreamIO/ds-tutorial-tanks

### Is there something stopping me from changing records in the database?

deepstream maintains its low latency by actually doing all the writes/reads to the cache. Writing to the database happens secondary in order not to introduce a hit. Because of this changing the record directly will not actually notify any of the users, as well as break some logic used for merge handling...

Comment: No, each type of records doesn't get it's own table. They are all stored in the `deepstream_records` table by default, but the table name can be changed with the `defaultTable` option, which is just a side note.

Comment: Def should, which db connector are you using?

Comment: That should work, you can only use a single '/' in the record name but other than that it has been tested multiple times. Worth raising an issue against the repo with your code to see where the issue lies.

Comment: Ahh, ok, I think I misunderstood then. I thought I created the users table with `rethinkdbdash`, and that all the `deepstream` data was kept in this one table, but I see my error now.